# How can I update a timestamp field in MySQL through Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have database table with the following schema,

### schema

> `hash VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, regional_unit VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW(), PRIMARY KEY (hash)`

that I update with the following statement through Python:

### query

```sql
INSERT INTO urls (hash, regional_unit, url, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=hash;
    [['...', '...', '...', None, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 21, 18, 55, 910026)],
     ['...', '...', '...', None, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 21, 18, 55, 910046)]]
```

My problem is that, based on the statements above, field `'created_at'` does not get updated, i.e. it always has the same value as `'created_at'` field.

**EDIT:**

```
INSERT INTO urls (hash, regional_unit, url, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=hash; [['...', '...', '...', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268424), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268437)], ['...', '...', '...', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268444), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268446)]]
```

**EDIT2:**

```
self.db_connect()
self.get_curs().executemany("""INSERT INTO urls (hash, regional_unit, url, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=hash;""", [['...', '...', '...', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268424), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268437)], ['...', '...', '...', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268444), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268446)]])
self.get_conn().commit()
self.db_disconnect()
```

Comment: `created_at` is your 4th field in query, you've set it to `None` for some reason ;-)

Comment: No. Unfortunately, this does not seem the problem. I edited my question, but still get the same problem...

Comment: but is this python code? I don't see python structure. and don't see query string. you mixed everything. show the real python code you use

Comment: ok, I have quoted my python code as well. Please have a look in you don't mind :)

Comment: @KimAlexander Please have a look on `EDIT2` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 12, 57, 268437).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

self.get_curs().executemany("""INSERT INTO urls (hash, regional_unit, url, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=hash;""", [['...', '...', '...', a, a], ['...', '...', '...', a,a]])
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work either... what else should I try?

Comment: so your table is empty before you start to insert? and it inserts everything except `created_at`?

Comment: my table is indeed empty the first time I run the query. but the second time, when the table has already one record, the field updated_at does not get updated for some reason... any ideas?

Comment: Well, not sore what you mean exactly... technically, I do not use UPDATE but rather a special case of INSERT.

Comment: yes, but you wrote `ON DUPLICATE`... `UPDATE hash`... so you didn't even try to update any field except the `hash` and even hash you don't try to update, you just asked to keep old value