# can't update date value MySQL python

Tags: python, mysql

I've tried looking at several similar questions to this issue, but they still don't seem to work for me for some reason.

**Error I'm getting**:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET stockPriceRef.ticker='NGVT' SET stockPriceRef.updateDate='2020-05-25 01:22:1' at line 1")
```

I've tried this without the time and it works, but I'd like to update the timestamp still.

**The query that I'm trying to use**:

```
'UPDATE stockPriceRef SET stockPriceRef.id=%s SET stockPriceRef.ticker=%s SET stockPriceRef.updateDate=%s SET stockPriceRef.open=%s SET stockPriceRef.high=%s SET stockPriceRef.low=%s SET stockPriceRef.close=%s SET stockPriceRef.volume=%s WHERE id=%s;'
```

```
# values tuple I am passing below:
#values: (1961, 'NGVT', '2020-05-25 01:22:18', 52.02, 52.315, 50.65, 51.45, 209950, 1961)
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```py
 # the update statement mentioned above
 update_stock_price_ref = create_update_prepared_statement('stockPriceRef', self.sql)
 # get out current time and format it
 time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 # call execute statement and pass values
 self.sql.execute_query(update_stock_price_ref,values=(ticker_id,ticker,time,price_summ['open'],price_summ['high'],
                                              price_summ['low'],price_summ['previousClose'], price_summ['volume'], ticker_id))
```

```py
def execute_query(self, query, values=None):
        """ execute a query  """
        # if you want to use ssh password use - ssh_password='your ssh password', bellow
        data = None
        #print('executing query: {}'.format(query))
        cursor = self.sql_conn.cursor()
        try:
            if(values is None):
                data = cursor.execute(query)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            else:
                if(type(values) is not tuple):
                    raise TypeError(f'Values should be of type tuple, type of {type(values)}')
                data = cursor.execute(query, values)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            if('INSERT' in query or 'UPDATE' in query):
                self.sql_conn.commit()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            print('query: {}'.format(query))
            print(f'values: {values}')
            return None
        #
        return data
```

I have also tried executing the statement from the mySQL console and it works for some reason, but when I call it from python it doesn't. Anything would be really helpful at this point.

**Edit:**
Here are some of the other questions I have looked at.
[updating-date-time-into-mysql-via-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441722/updating-date-time-into-mysql-via-python)
[datetime-date-value-not-updating-into-mysql-database-in-python-correctly-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270990/datetime-date-value-not-updating-into-mysql-database-in-python-correctly-update)
[how-can-i-update-a-timestamp-field-in-mysql-through-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636846/how-can-i-update-a-timestamp-field-in-mysql-through-python)

**EDIT 2**
thanks to [klaus-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d), they pointed out I had more than one SET in the query. Looked at the mySQL documentation and saw some other issues with my query.

```
UPDATE stockPriceRef SET id=%s,ticker=%s,updateDate=%s,open=%s,high=%s,low=%s,close=%s,volume=%s WHERE id=%s;
```

Comment: Only one `SET` is allowed in the query.

Comment: Yup this got me the right direction! Thanks a lot. Saw a few other errors I had too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query.

```
UPDATE
   stockPriceRef 
SET
   stockPriceRef.id =% s, stockPriceRef.ticker =% s, stockPriceRef.updateDate =% s, stockPriceRef.open =% s, stockPriceRef.high =% s, stockPriceRef.low =% s, stockPriceRef.close =% s, stockPriceRef.volume =% s 
WHERE
   id =% s;
```

For prepared statement refer this : 
https://github.com/aviboy2006/flask-rest-api/blob/master/database.py#L39